# Is it possible to specify the output file path and let NASM decide the extension?

Tags: nasm

When I use NASM without specifying the output file, NASM decides the extension according to the output format.

For example, if I run NASM with output format "bin", it will create the output file with extension ".bin", if the output format is "win32", the extension is ".obj",...

Is it possible to specify the output file, and let NASM detect the output file extension according to the output format?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I read the docs and didn't find anything about this. I also tried passing a file without extension as output path, but it didn't work. If I don't specify an output path, the file is created with the correct extension as expected, but I can't choose the path...

Comment: As far as out of box behavior I think you've tried what you could. Nothing short of a script/wrapper would work.

Comment: AFAIK, no.  The `-o` option always takes a full pathname, not a template or basename.